# Google App Scripts Method to Create a Shortcut to Google Drive File

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to automate the process of creating a shortcut/link to a Google file as one would manually do by right-clicking on a file and seeing the below screen and clicking "Add shortcut to Drive"

[image]

Looking through [Google's Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) on `file` object shows no actionable methods of this feature, only pulls (i.e. `getTargetId()`, etc).

I'm pretty sure this isn't available but I thought I'd throw it out there and see if anyone had any ideas. I see a couple posts using some external API's and firefox which isn't what I'm trying to do.

If I were to guess what code such code would look like, it would be something like this....

```
function makeSomeFileLink(){
  var theFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("wdflasdjflaskdjfklsadjflk")
  var aFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1VjOkMPBDr???????????qkZqPCQWOvBbIt_6GawA");
  var myNewBookMark = aFile.makeShortCutAndPutInInThisFolder(theFolder);
}
```

Obviously, that last row of code is problematic (i.e. I made it up), I'm just trying to illustrate what I'm looking for.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to create a shortcut of the file `aFile` to the folder of `theFolder`, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```
function makeSomeFileLink(){
  var theFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("wdflasdjflaskdjfklsadjflk");
  var aFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1VjOkMPBDr???????????qkZqPCQWOvBbIt_6GawA");
  DriveApp.createShortcut(aFile.getId()).moveTo(theFolder);
}
```

- Of course, in this case, you can directly put the file ID of `"1VjOkMPBDr???????????qkZqPCQWOvBbIt_6GawA"` to `createShortcut`.

#### Reference:

- [createShortcut(targetId)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createshortcuttargetid)

Comment: OMG! How did I miss that!  I was looking in the File reference not the overalll app... I have to wait 2 more minutes to accept, but well done...

Comment: @pgSystemTester Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Although this is just my guess, I guessed that the Google side might have wanted to add this method as same as creating a file.